# Batch Programming, copying mutliple files from multiple folders to one folder sorted by date

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently trying to get a small batch working which is able to copy PDF and TXT files from "several folders" to one folder which is sorted by date MM-YYYY.

I already got some code working, but its still not finished, I currently stuck on the multiple folders and to add the TXT.

```
set "source=c:\Program Files (x86)\Temp1"  
set "target=c:\Temp2"  
for %%i in (%source%\*.pdf) do @for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in 
("%%~ti") do (
    if not exist "%target%\%%C\%%B" mkdir "%target%\%%C\%%B"
    move "%%~fi" "%target%\%%C\%%B"
)
```

This is working fine (except the space in the name, but I awesome I will find the issue with the dos file names). But I also what to search in several folders.

Like.

```
set "source=c:\Program Files (x86)\Temp1"  
set "source=c:\Program Files (x86)\Temp2"
set "source=c:\Program Files (x86)\Temp3"  

set "target=c:\Temp2"  

for %%i in (%source%*.pdf)+(%source%*.txt)
```

something in this direction, I simply tried to repeat the code and exchanged to source only, but this does not work like that, so I will stuck aswell with the .txt.

If somebody has an idea, I would be very happy :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to staying with a simple `for` to iterate the pdf files is to change into source folder.

To iterate several source folders enclose in another `for`:
(Untested)

```
@Echo off

set "source=c:\Program Files (x86)"  
set "target=c:\Temp2"

For %%S in (Temp1 Temp2 Temp3) do (
    PushD "%source%\%%S"
    for %%I in (*.pdf) do for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ("%%~tI") do (
        if not exist "%target%\%%C\%%B" mkdir "%target%\%%C\%%B"
        move "%%~fI" "%target%\%%C\%%B\"
    )
    PopD
)
```